# Using SSO in a third party controlled web view in Flutter Web

Tags: flutter, single-sign-on, flutter-web

I'm using various SSO options such as [Google](https://pub.dev/packages/google_sign_in) for my Flutter Web app which generally work fine. If opened in a web browser the sign in dialog is opened either in a popup (desktop) or a new tab (mobile).

However, when the link to my app is shared in e.g. Facebook and opened through the Facebook app, a webview inside the Facebook app opens my app. This webview does not allow tabs, therefore the sign in dialog is opened in the current view, overriding my Flutter App. This prevents any SSO from being used when opening the app this way (e.g. through the Facebook app)

I've tried forcing the app to launch in the default browser instead of the Facebook web view but wasn't able to do so.

Is there any way to open the default browser even when the link to my app is opened from within the Facebook app?

Or

Is there any way to provide access to the (e.g. Google) authentication screen without killing my app in the process?